# OL3 How to select features, cluster inside a polygon

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm trying to check features inside a polygon:

```
function howinpol(evt) {
    var polygon_extent = evt.feature.getGeometry().getExtent(); // get polygone extent
    var starr_uli = "", arr_fdgdg = [];

    mySource8.forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent(polygon_extent, function(feature) {
        xl = parseFloat(feature.get('lon')); // get lon
        yl = parseFloat(feature.get('lat')); // get lat
        feature.setProperties({ visible: 'visible' });  // add prop
        feature.setProperties({ inpol: 'in' }); // add prop
        arr_fdgdg.push(feature); // add features
        // list
        starr_uli += '<li><span id="'+ feature.getId() +'">' + feature.get('name_kontr') + '&nbsp;&nbsp; id:' + feature.getId() + '</span><small>'+ feature.get('billing_address_city') +', '+ feature.get('billing_address_street') +'</small></li>';
    });

    $('#objects ul').replaceWith('<ul>' + starr_uli + '</ul>'); //name list

    $('#cntobj').text(arr_fdgdg.length); //count in list

    mySource8.clear(); //clear 
    mySource8.addFeatures(arr_fdgdg); //add select features
}
```

but it is beyond the scope if draw a circle or freehand polygon:
[image]

I tried to wrap if(evt.feature.getGeometry().intersectsCoordinate([xl, yl])):

```
function howinpol(evt) {
    var polygon_extent = evt.feature.getGeometry().getExtent(); // get polygone extent
    var starr_uli = "", arr_fdgdg = [];

    mySource8.forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent(polygon_extent, function(feature) {
        xl = parseFloat(feature.get('lon')); // get lon
        yl = parseFloat(feature.get('lat')); // get lat

        if(evt.feature.getGeometry().intersectsCoordinate([xl, yl])){
            feature.setProperties({ visible: 'visible' });  // add prop
            feature.setProperties({ inpol: 'in' }); // add prop
            arr_fdgdg.push(feature); // add features
            // list
            starr_uli += '<li><span id="'+ feature.getId() +'">' + feature.get('name_kontr') + '&nbsp;&nbsp; id:' + feature.getId() + '</span><small>'+ feature.get('billing_address_city') +', '+ feature.get('billing_address_street') +'</small></li>';
        }
    });

    $('#objects ul').replaceWith('<ul>' + starr_uli + '</ul>'); //name list

    $('#cntobj').text(arr_fdgdg.length); //count in list

    mySource8.clear(); //clear 
    mySource8.addFeatures(arr_fdgdg); //add select features
}
```

It worked, but it loops through a very long time.

have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem myself:

```
    function howinpol(evt) {
       var polygon_extent = evt.feature.getGeometry().getExtent(); // get polygone extent
       var starr_uli = "", arr_fdgdg = [], mass = [];

       mySource8.forEachFeatureIntersectingExtent(polygon_extent, function(feature) {
          xl = parseFloat(feature.get('lon')); // get lon
          yl = parseFloat(feature.get('lat')); // get lat

          uli_p = '<li><span id="'+ feature.getId() +'">' + feature.get('name_kontr') + '&nbsp;&nbsp; id:' + feature.getId() + '</span><small>'+ feature.get('billing_address_city') +', '+ feature.get('billing_address_street') +'</small></li>'; 
          mass.push({id: feature.getId(), feature: feature, uli_p: uli_p, xl: xl, yl: yl});

       });

       for(var i = 0; i < mass.length; i++){
          if(evt.feature.getGeometry().intersectsCoordinate([mass[i].xl, mass[i].yl])){
             var selfeatu = mass[i].feature;
             arr_fdgdg.push(selfeatu);
             starr_uli += uli_p;
          }
       }

       $('#objects ul').replaceWith('<ul>' + starr_uli + '</ul>'); //name list

       $('#cntobj').text(arr_fdgdg.length); //count in list

       mySource8.clear(); //clear 
       mySource8.addFeatures(arr_fdgdg); //add select features
   }
```

I have added an array when forEchFeatureIntersektingEstent
and then sort out, not all the features, but only those that received.

It works much faster.

p/s: I'm sorry for Google translator